# How can I introduce Slim framework in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, slim

I want to introduce Slim framework into my XAMPP but I don't know where I have to allocate the folder. I was searching through the folders of xampp folder but I didn't see any of them that could be the right way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question confuses me.  Slim framework is a micro PHP framework and does not interface with MySQL.  PhpMyAdmin is an accessor to your MySQL database.  I think you're miss-understanding something about what you want to implement.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself in a bad way, sorry. I mean that I want to introduce my Slim framework in my server and I'm using XAMPP, I don't know if it clears more the question. Sorry but I'm really new in this field.

Comment: Did you write an app with Slim that you want to put on the server?

Comment: @earl3s I downloaded the .zip from the official page and want to add it into my server. Later I will want to use Slim with my app, right.

Comment: You'll want to put it in an accessible folder on your server.  Which one that is depends on what version of linux you're running.  There is a lot that goes into this and there's no way I can answer this for you in any kind of short time.

Comment: @earl3s Thank you man but I got the answer!. I'm going to edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I just allocate the folder of Slim framework in `C:\xampp\htdocs\project` where `project` it's the folder of my app. It works properly.

Answer (score 0):

for use mysql in slim you can use propel or eloquent.I created a stack slim,eloquent,twig you can try this.https://github.com/kingpabel/est-stack

Comment: I don't really understand your answer but anyway I got the answer. I will edit my question. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Error404 to close the question you should flag the correct answer using the tick that is on the left of the answer and not changing the title of the question. Can you please update your question? thank you!

Comment: @LelioFaieta but I got my answer for my own and maybe it will be useful for someone. I edit my question with the solution. How can I close the question in this way?

Comment: @Error404 in this case you should write your own anwser to the question and mark that as solved. The goal is for other that have the same issue to come here and find the solution.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Ok I post it but I can't mark it like the answer. I expect now I'm in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Ubuntu, you should create a folder inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project`. Where **`my_project`** is the project folder.